# Search for a value on a database column splitting the value where there is a blank space

Tags: mysql

I have a table on my database named **leads**. Inside that table there are several columns containing the name, telephone, address, postal code etc, etc... of the leads.

The column that contains the name of the leads is called **clientName**.   As an example we have **Loyalty Logistics**.

I have an input type text inside a form where users search for a specific client name and shows the results on a Popup.   Right now I am using a WHERE clause

```
....WHERE leads.clientName LIKE "%'.$_POST["keyword"].'%"
```

The way it is right now it will only show up the client **Loyalty Logistics** 
if the user type **Loyalty** or **Logistics** or **Loyalty Logistics**, but in the case the user made a mistake and typed **Loyalti Logistics** I would also like to be able to show on the results all the clients that contained **Logistics** on its name.

Comment: Just type it correctly!

Comment: If I would be the only user I wouldn't have this problem but the users that are using my program are old and make lots of mistakes.

Comment: Could you construct some kind of autosuggest in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the split with your server side language (PHP, Python, JS ...) and obtain a list of keywords and make your sql request with it.

```
keywords = split(keyword)
for key in keywords 
    ....WHERE leads.clientName LIKE "%'.$_POST["key"].'%"
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Good idea.   I am a PHP developer.  Thanks a lot.